# Can I use multiple intro.js with more than 2 pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I want to use intro.js with more than two pages. 
Is it a simple way to do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think you've really provided enough information for anyone to help you. I suggest having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and trying again.

Comment: @RichChurcher This is the nicest comment to a new user (e.g. poorly asked question) I've ever read...  kudos to you and to Basia for keeping this site awesome :) (would have left you a pm, but couldn't see where to do it... so here it will have to reside until someone removes it )

Comment: Well, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. If you look at code for intro.js example with multiple pages https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/tree/master/example/multi-page you can see that first page has code that redirects to second page after user click the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function() {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page').start().oncomplete(function() {
      window.location.href = 'second.html?multipage=true';
    });
  };
</script>
```

And on the second page we use regex to check if user is going through intro. You will need  to add code like that to each page, with url address to the page that should be shown next. 
If you want to have more than one "intro flows" (since the question title said `multiple`), you can give them names or numbers. Then, instead of adding `multipage=true` you can use `multipage=beta_version` or `multipage=1` and use reqex to check if user should see intro, and if yes, which one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {

    document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function() {
      introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page')
        .start().oncomplete(function() {
          if (RegExp('multipage=2', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
            window.location.href = 'third.html?multipage=2';
          }
          else {
            window.location.href = 'unicorn.html?multipage=3';
          }
        });
      };
  }
</script>
```

That might be not the nicest code ever :), but ( like Rich said ) without more information I can only guess this is what you want to do? But hopefully, it will give a general idea.

Comment: you are awesome for adding an answer to such a lean question... this was very helpful for me as this is exactly what I'm in the middle of trying to accomplish... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next Page →').start().oncomplete(function() {
        window.location.href = 'nextpage?multipage=true';
    });
}

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) In addition, when posting answers consisting primarily of a code snippet, please [add some text to explain what the code does](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). You should also take the time to [format your code properly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use intro.js for a complex multipage use (more complete than their [official multipage example](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/tree/master/example/multi-page)). See the [issue I opened about it](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/1253) associated to [my React solution on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-ramanujan-fvxmd).