# How can I make multipage intro by using Intro.js programmatic

Tags: javascript, intro.js

Hello I just start learning with javascript and I would like to know how to make multipage intro by using intro.js

```
   function beginer() {
    var intro = introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
        {
            element: '#beginer1',
            intro: "This is a <b>bold</b> tooltip."
        },
        {
            element: '#beginer2',
            intro: "Ok, <i>wasn't</i> that fun?",
            position: 'bottom'
        },

        ]
    });

    intro.setOptions({
        'showStepNumbers': false
    });

    intro.start();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple intro.js with more than 2 pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135590/can-i-use-multiple-intro-js-with-more-than-2-pages)

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as combining the options given in the `multipage` and `programmatic` examples in the repo. The multipage example is [here](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/tree/master/example/multi-page)

All you got to do is add an `onComplete` listener on the first page like so:

```
function beginer() {
   var intro = introJs();
   intro.setOptions({
    showStepNumbers: false,
    doneLabel: "Next page",
    steps: [
    {
        element: '#beginer1',
        intro: "This is a <b>bold</b> tooltip."
    },
    {
        element: '#beginer2',
        intro: "Ok, <i>wasn't</i> that fun?",
        position: 'bottom'
    },

    ]
   });

  intro.start().oncomplete(function() {
      window.location.href = 'second.html?multipage=true';
  });
}
```

I have sanitized the `setOptions` call in your function and combined all the options there. So that you don't have to do `setOptions` multiple `doneLabel` param. I guess, it triggers the `oncomplete` method which is defined after `intro.start()`. It redirects to the *next* page which in my case is `second.html`. Remember to pass the param `multipage=true`.

`second.html` is a regular HTML file but you need to start the `introJs` function to make the whole transition mulitpage. All you do is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
    introJs().start();
  }
</script>
```

This in essence triggers the `introJs().start()` function after it finds the word `multipage` in the url or href in your browser address bar. Remember we called `second.html` like `second.html?multipage=true`. This just starts another *intro* instance on the second page. Now you can define the options here in form of JSON if you want or just use the `data-step` attributes on DOM as defined in the docs.

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, for the next page function is working but how can I define JSON within this code

Comment: The next intro step isn't auto run when the next page start

Comment: @Thida, just like you define the `steps` object in your first file, just like that you'll have to do `IntroJs.setOptions()` and set the `steps` object. You will have to provide the JSON of the steps to be shown in the second page. So the JSON for first and second page would be different.

Comment: I had try this, but it still not working. Can you please check my code below of second page? I think there something wrong but I just can't figured it out where.

Comment: <code><script type="text/javascript">
  
  if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
    
    
   introJs().setOptions({
    showStepNumbers: false,
    
    steps: [
    {
        element: '#beginer3',
        intro: "This is a <b>bold</b> tooltip."
    },
    {
        element: '#beginer4',
        intro: "Ok, <i>wasn't</i> that fun?",
        position: 'bottom'
    },

    ]
   });
   introJs().start();

}

</script></code>